# Python: Not all arguments converted during string formatting when inserting into Mysql

Tags: python, mysql

I want to insert multiple records into Mysql using python.

I have tried something like:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    req_json = request.get_json(force=True)
    dir(req_json)
    #sys.exit()
    g.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO gmr (version,visitorId,dwellTime,poiId,srId,zoneId,poiProximityConfidence,zoneProximityConfidence,poiPresenceConfidence,zonePresenceConfidence,normalizedTime) VALUES ({0},{1},{2},{3},{4},{5},{6},{7},{8},{9},{10})",
                         (req_json[0]['version'], req_json[0]['visitorId'], req_json[0]['dwellTime'], req_json[0]['poiId'], req_json[0]['srId'], req_json[0]['zoneId'], req_json[0]['poiProximityConfidence'], req_json[0]['zoneProximityConfidence'], req_json[0]['poiPresenceConfidence'], req_json[0]['zonePresenceConfidence'], req_json[0]['normalizedTime']))
```

Im passing json objects like:

```
 [  
 {  
  "dwellTime":"2",
  "normalizedTime":"1489574977000",
  "poiId":"poi3",
  "poiPresenceConfidence":"15",
  "poiProximityConfidence":"1",
  "srId":"sr3",
  "version":"15",
  "visitorId":"V123",
  "zoneId":"Security",
  "zonePresenceConfidence":"40",
  "zoneProximityConfidence":"20"
 },
 {  
  "dwellTime":"234234",
  "normalizedTime":"1489574977000",
  "poiId":"poi3",
  "poiPresenceConfidence":"15",
  "poiProximityConfidence":"1",
  "srId":"sr3",
  "version":"16",
  "visitorId":"V123",
  "zoneId":"Security",
  "zonePresenceConfidence":"40",
  "zoneProximityConfidence":"20"
}
]
```

I get the error like:

**ProgrammingError: not all arguments converted during string formatting**

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "/root/python-mysql/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1997, in call return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "/root/python-mysql/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1985, in wsgi_app response = self.handle_exception(e)
File "/root/python-mysql/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1540, in handle_exception reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/root/python-mysql/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "/root/python-mysql/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "/root/python-mysql/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb) File "/root/python-mysql/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "/root/python-mysql/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request return self.view_functionsrule.endpoint
File "/root/python-mysql/venv/py_gmr.py", line 56, in add (req_json[0]['version'], req_json[0]['visitorId'], req_json[0]['dwellTime'], req_json[0]['poiId'], req_json[0]['srId'], req_json[0]['zoneId'], req_json[0]['poiProximityConfidence'], req_json[0]['zoneProximityConfidence'], req_json[0]['poiPresenceConfidence'], req_json[0]['zonePresenceConfidence'], req_json[0]['normalizedTime']))
File "/root/python-mysql/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 283, in executemany self.rowcount = sum(self.execute(query, arg) for arg in args)
File "/root/python-mysql/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 283, in self.rowcount = sum(self.execute(query, arg) for arg in args)
File "/root/python-mysql/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 240, in execute self.errorhandler(self, ProgrammingError, str(m))
File "/root/python-mysql/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 52, in defaulterrorhandler raise errorclass(errorvalue) ProgrammingError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

If I replace `{0}, {1}` with `%s`, only a single value gets inserted

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `{}` as placeholders in an SQL statement. You must use `%s`.

Using `{}` wouldn't fix your "problem" with only inserting a single set of values. That is *to be expected*, because you are only accessing the first set of values in your JSON. If you want to insert them both, you need to *iterate* over the values with a for loop and insert one set each time - as you would when trying to do anything with any list.

Comment: I am using %s instead of {0}, as told oly 1 record is inserting pls give an example on using the loop for the same

Comment: I really think you need to do a basic programming tutorial. I'm not trying to be unhelpful, but writing a loop should be one of the first things you learned how to do.